# Matching the image with its background color?

Tags: inkscape, images, background

Any idea on how to make the white region the same color as the light brown background without bothering the axis, or curves?

[image]

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Baymax, can you tell something more about the image? Is the graphic generated in Inkscape (and if it is so, you can simply remove the white background) or in an external application? Have you tried to use a [mask](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Clip.html)? The work seems more suitable for Gimp, perhaps.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  In Inkscape you could set the blend mode of the graph image to Multiply.  You can do this in the Fill & Stroke panel. Select the graph image, Scroll to the bottom of the panel, and set the blend mode to Multiply.

Answer (score 2):

If the graph is a vector image do as already said by others: Explode it and remove the white background object. If it happens to be a bitmap image PNG JPG, TIF etc.. and cannot be disassembled, then use blending modes. Multiply is already suggested. It fades completely the white and black stays intact. Unfortunately other colors are mixed with the non-white background. That can be OK if the other graph colors are dark and the background is quite light as it's now.

Darken is another blending mode which works if the graph colors are all darker than the background. It's used in the next image. A piece of your background is stretched below the graph:

[image]

As you see, the blue and black stay both intact. If the graph has also light colors you must darken them. To do it for a bitmap image use GIMP.

Comment: Great answer. Welcome to GDSE!